# Place div1 under div4 when div1 html code is on top of div4

Tags: html, css

I have a page with lots of content

```
<div1></div1>

<div2></div2>

<div3>
    <div4></div4>
</div3>
<div5></div5>
```

how is it possible to display the div1 underneath div4 without modifying the html ?

the desired 'rendered' output should look as if it was written like this:

```
<div2></div2>

<div3>
    <div4></div4>
    <div1></div1>
</div3>
<div5></div5>
```

but instead it should be written like the first code block

Comment: Have you tried CSS positioning?

Comment: Is that something that you want to happen every time or just under certain conditions? What do you use to check for these conditions? You can easily add a empty `div5` under `div4` and use `JavaScript` or `jQuery` to transfer the contents of `div1` to `div5`

Comment: @tylerh (and others who marked the question as duplicate) may I know what this question is duplicate of? have't found any information or working examples or anyone asking even a similar question. please provide at least one link and excuse my inability to find a duplicate question or a proper answer. P.S the linked answer didn't solve my problem